# Displaying error message using html5 and kendo ui

Tags: html, c#-4.0, kendo-ui

I am working in html5 and css3 and got stuck in one condition. The condition is "the warning message should display when button is clicked" after the button not textbox. Its looked simple but when i done coding i got below output.

[image]

but it should display after scan button. can somebody help me?

here is my coding.

.aspx

```
<label class="moblblText">Moveable Unit / Location:</label>                     
                    <input type="text" id="txtunitId" runat="server" class="k-textbox" style="width:120px" name="search" maxlength="11" required validationMessage="Please Enter Digits"/>
                 <button  class="loginBtn" style="width:150px" runat="server" TabIndex="0"  ID="btnScan">Scan</button> 
                  <li class="status">
                </li>
```

.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var validator = $("#txtunitId").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator"),

       status = $(".status");

        $("button").click(function () {
            if (validator.validate()) {

            } else {

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ft2Xa/1/

Comment: @SpikeX : button is always static. it should not move when user clicked it. it is not good ui design. i need the message should display after button but witout pushing button.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't necessarily solve your problem, but you have malformed HTML:

```
<input ...maxlength="11" required validationMessage=<\n> "Please Enter Digits"/>
```

It should probably be:

```
<input ...maxlength="11" required validationMessage="Please Enter Digits"/>
```

Comment: I said, "this doesn't solve your problem", but you should still fix it as it has the potential to cause problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label class="moblblText" style="float:left;">Moveable Unit / Location:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtunitId" runat="server" class="k-textbox" style="width:120px;float:left;" name="search" maxlength="11" required validationMessage="Please Enter Digits" />
<button class="loginBtn" style="width:150px;float:left;" runat="server" TabIndex="0" ID="btnScan">Scan</button>



var validator = $("#txtunitId").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator"),
    status = $(".status");

$('#txtunitId').focusout(function(){
  $("#txtunitId").next().find("span").css("float", "right");

});

$("button").click(function () {
    if (validator.validate()){

    } else {

    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ft2Xa/3/